# How to insert a token to CKEditor (no Drupal)

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, token, wysiwyg

I want to use a wysiwyg editor (preferably but not necessarily CKEditor) alongside with a token insert feature.

I have found **Token Insert** module but I don't want to use Drupal. Is there anything else that I can use to insert a token from a list while writing content in a wysiwyg editor?

Comment: I want to insert custom strings (e.g. --> ##Customer_Name## ) that will be then replaced by specific value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the Placeholder feature for CKEditor matches your needs:

- Sample, with source code to download: http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/placeholder.html
- Documentation: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_placeholder

Comment: You're welcome, hope this helps. Anyway, feel free to browse the [CKEditor SDK](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/) for other ideas and implementations of different editor features (and believe me, there are lots of them!).